# iloc in pandas showing data that i dont want

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

i am using pandas in python to locate certain data in my CSV file using iloc. It is returning the data that i want but also returning data values that i don't want(The row numbers and column names).

[My Csv File is : ] [1]: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsdoG.jpg

And my code is :

```
import pandas as pd

ctr_x = []
ctr_y =[]

obj = 'red_hat'
df = pd.read_csv('ring_1_05_sam.csv',)
ctr_x = df.iloc[10:12, 0:1 ]
ctr_y = df.iloc[10:12, 1:2]

print(ctr_x)
print(ctr_y)
```

The output that i get is :

```
version
10  1536.25
11  1536.50
     3
10  895.25
11  896.00
```

So i am also getting the Row numbers and column names along with my desired result. Any idea how i get rid of these row numbers and column names?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I get my desired result

Comment: Ok if i just want to save my date into ctr_x[] and ctr_y[] lists without printing and without index and header, can you please tell mew how may i do it